# How to pass a property from popup to execute

Tags: python, bezier-curves, add-on

I'm writing a Curve Outline Addon which works quite nice as a script, but I'm getting confused with the UI integration: I would like a simple popup asking for the Outline amount which interactively shows on my Curve. Instead I have a popup which forwards my property to the execute and then applies to my Curve.

Somewhere I didn't completely grasp the concept of modal/pass_through and invoke/execute...

```
class CurveOutline(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Curve Outliner"""
    bl_idname = "object._curve_outline"
    bl_label = "Create Outline"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    outline = bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="Outline", default=0.1, min=-10, max=10)

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.object.type == 'CURVE'

    def execute(self, context):
        createOutline(context.selected_objects[0], self.outline)
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`invoke_props_dialog()` opens a "blocking" popup, it won't call `execute()` with the updated values until user confirm with *OK* button.

Use `invoke_props_popup()` instead, if you want to immediately re-run the operation:

```
import bpy

class CurveOutline(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Curve Outliner"""
    bl_idname = "object._curve_outline"
    bl_label = "Create Outline"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    outline = bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="Outline", default=0.1, min=-10, max=10)

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return (context.object is not None and
                context.object.type == 'CURVE')

    def execute(self, context):
        createOutline(context.object, self.outline)
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        return context.window_manager.invoke_props_popup(self, event)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(CurveOutline)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(CurveOutline)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Added a check for `context.object is not None` to ensure the operator isn't run with no active object and replace `selected_objects[0]` by `object`, as it's not the same. If you intended to work on multiple selected objects, get all selected objects and remove the active one from list to separate them.

Comment: Thanks a lot, a bit frustrating being so close though... Now I have a working Curve Outliner which I'm happy to share btw!

Answer (score 0):

You can set an update callback on the FloatProperty. I'm not sure it is actually safe to use it with invoke_props_dialog() but I tried and it works.

Replace the line `outline = bpy.props...` by:

```
def update_outline(self, context):
    createOutline(context.selected_objects[0], self.outline)

outline = bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="Outline", default=0.1, 
        min=-10, max=10, update=update_outline)
```